# What does 엄칭히 mean?

Tags: dialects, slang

I am watching the film 용순 (Yongsoon), set in 충청도. I have come across a believed adverb 엄칭히 twice in the film. Caveat: my listening comprehension is beginner's level, so I am using the native korean subs, and english subs to watch it:

> > "**엄칭히** 대간한대 계주는 빼 줘" sub tl: Let me off the relay?

(My attempt is "Coach, I am so exhausted, please could you take me off the relay team?")

and a second example:

> > "해 **엄칭히** 기네" sub tl: Why is the sun up so long?

My guess is that it means 'very', but I cannot find it in a K-E dictionary, so if someone can give me a definition and some background, that would be very helpful!

Comment: Your guess is correct. [엄칭이](https://opendict.korean.go.kr/dictionary/view?sense_no=865442) (or 엄칭히) is a dialect word. The standard word is 엄청.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Very' is a good translation. As you said, I couldn't find it in a Korean-English dictionary, but [it is in a Korean dictionary](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/c8d891944e2247b196d06274b4d9dc28). 엄청이 is Chungcheong dialect for 엄청.

As a side note, I would recommend you try to use the Korean dictionary, because there are more entries and so that you can practice thinking in Korean.

Answer (score 2):

I'm korean student in high school:), thank you for your attention to Korean. not 엄칭히, it is 엄청. 
There are various expression '엄청'. Because local speaking is very deveoloped in Korean. we called that is 사투리(so I think, if you really listening 엄칭히, that is local speaking). In Busan, I tell 엄청 to 억수로. Like, 엄청 맛있네! (very delicious!), = 억수로 맛있네!

I hope that you are keeping being interested in Korean!! :) Have a nice day! 좋은 하루 보내세요 ㅎㅎ(ㅎㅎ= :) )

Comment: 부산도 SMS의 거울 들어줘 감사합니다!